# How to terminate all prior threads if a thread of the same type is run [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx

so suppose I have a function that runs Thread1 called fucntionA
Now Thread 1 takes 10 seconds to run and finish

But suppose I call function A again, within 5 seconds of calling it the first time, such that the first instance of Thread1 is still running

I want the first instance of Thread1 to terminate, once the new instance is called.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Abra no, I don't want to wait for thread 1 to finish processing before thread 2 starts,
Because Thread 2 will have the most recent input data and the output data of thread 1 would be useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code launches a thread. Then, after a short pause (to simulate the first thread taking time to complete), a second thread is launched but before launching the second thread, the first thread is terminated.

```java
public class Cesation implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean quit;

    public synchronized void cease() {
        quit = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long total = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        while (!quit) {
            if (total == Long.MAX_VALUE) {
                total = Long.MIN_VALUE;
            }
            total++;
        }
        System.out.println("Final total = " + total);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cesation c1 = new Cesation();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(c1);
        t1.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        Cesation c2 = new Cesation();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(c2);
        c1.cease();
        try {
            t1.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException x1) {
            x1.printStackTrace();
        }
        t2.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        c2.cease();
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not make the other thread stop until it checks, need a add a loop before u start the 2nd thtead to make sure first has stopped and then start t2. If thread 1 is wasiting on some I/O or other lock that can take a few milli seconds or more